# Zeromq (pyzmq) ROUTER procession of multiple clients' data and subsequent timeout handling

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, zeromq

I have a `ROUTER` whose purpose is to accumulate image data from multiple `DEALER` clients and perform OCR on the complete image. I found that the most efficient way of handling the OCR is through the utilization of Python's multiprocessing library; the accumulated image bytes are `put` into a `Queue` for due procession in a separate `Process`. However, I need to ensure that when a client experiences a timeout that the `Process` is properly terminated and doesn't meaninglessly linger and hog resources.

In my current solution I insert each newly-connected client into a `dict` where the `value` is my `ClientHandler` class that possesses all image data and spawns a `Thread` that sets a `boolean` variable named "timeout" to `True` when 5 seconds have elapsed. Should a new message be received within that 5 second frame, `bump` is called & the timer is reset back to 0, otherwise I cleanup prior to thread termination and the reference is deleted from the `dict` in the main loop:

```
import threading
import time
import zmq

class ClientHandler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.elapsed = time.time()
        self.timeout = False

        self.socket = socket

        super(ClientHandler, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while time.time() - self.elapsed < 5.0:
            pass

        self.timeout = True

        # CLIENT TIMED OUT
        # HANDLE TERMINATION AND CLEAN UP HERE

    def bump(self):
        self.elapsed = time.time()

    def handle(self, id, header, data):
        # HANDLE CLIENT DATA HERE
        # ACCUMULATE IMAGE BYTES, ETC

        self.socket.send_multipart([id, str(0)])

def server_task():
    clients = dict()

    context = zmq.Context.instance()
    server = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)

    server.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, 0)

    server.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:7777")

    while True:
        try:
            id, header, data = server.recv_multipart()

            client = clients.get(id)

            if client == None:
                client = clients[id] = ClientHandler(server)

                client.start()

            client.bump()
            client.handle(id, header, data)
        except zmq.Again:
            for id in clients.keys():
                if clients[id].timeout:
                    del clients[id]

    context.term()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_task()
```

But this entire method just doesn't *feel* right. Am I going about this improperly? If so, I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: My brother had suggested that I assign a port for each client connecting and simply handle each individual timeout there, rather than handling this whole dictionary mess. I'll provide & mark the answer once I muster the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself, hoping it may be of assistance to others.

I instead have a ROUTER on an assigned port that distributes unique ports to each client, which thereafter connects to the newly-bound socket on said unique port. When a client disconnects, the port is recycled for reassignment.

```
import sys
import zmq
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Value

def server_task():
    context = zmq.Context.instance()

    server = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)

    server.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:7777")

    timeout_queue = Queue()
    port_list = [ 1 ]

    proc_list = [ ]

    while True:
        try:
            id = server.recv_multipart()[0]

            # Get an unused port from the list
            # Ports from clients that have timed out are recycled here

            while not timeout_queue.empty():
                port_list.append(timeout_queue.get())

            port = port_list.pop()

            if len(port_list) == 0:
                port_list.append(port + 1)

            # Spawn a new worker task, binding the port to a socket

            proc_running = Value("b", True)

            proc_list.append(proc_running)

            Process(target=worker_task, args=(proc_running, port, timeout_queue)).start()

            # Send the new port to the client

            server.send_multipart([id, str(7777 + port)])

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    # Safely allow our worker processes to terminate
    for proc_running in proc_list:
        proc_running.value = False

    context.term()

def worker_task(proc_running, port, timeout_queue):
    context = zmq.Context.instance()

    worker = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)

    worker.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, 5000)
    worker.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:%d" % (7777 + port, ))

    while proc_running.value:
        try:
            id, data = worker.recv_multipart()

            worker.send_multipart([id, data])
        except zmq.Again:
            timeout_queue.put(port)

            context.term()

            break

    print("Client on port %d disconnected" % (7777 + port, ))
```